# D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 option does not work for me

Tags: gcc, g++, fortify-source

I saw that GCC 4.5 and above versions should support –D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 option. But it does not work for me, it has been ignred and it does not report issues when i used.

Compiler version used is "g++.c4.5.3-p0", Will it ignore the option?

Comment: Can you add [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Answer (score 2):

In most systems, `–D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2` is only activated when also using `-O2`, ie, GCC compiler optimizations level 2 (or more). Try to use `-O2 –D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2` to see if it works.

Comment: I was thinking if -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE is on by default. I found that only with -O2 the fortification function could be instrumented.  I checked with gcc-10.